# Get href value while clicking li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the code of the `Div` which is created dynamically.

```
<div align="right" class="row pagination">
  <ul class="pagination pagination">
   <li class="prev disabled"><span>Previous Label</span></li> 
   <li class="active"><span>1</span></li> 
   <li><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="/some_url?page=3">3</a></li> 
   <li class="next"><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">Next Label</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

When I click any `<li>` tag, I need to take the href value(eg: /some_url?page=2) of corresponding `<li>` tag.

```
$("ul.pagination li").click(function(e) {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

In the above code, clicking event is firing but i am getting undefined in the alert.

Please help.

Comment: $(this) always give current object. i.e. li. That's a reason it doesn't hv href value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i am getting undefined in the alert.

Yes because you're trying to alert the `href` of the clicked `li` when it has no attribute `href`.

You need to alert the `href` of the anchor inside the `li` using `a` in your selector, or also using `.find()` like :

```
alert( $('a', this).attr('href') );
//Or also
alert( $(this).find('a').attr('href') );
```

You could also attach the click event directly to the child anchors of the `il`'s like :

```
$("ul.pagination li a").click(function(e) {
  alert( $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

```js
$("ul.pagination li").click(function(e) {
  alert($('a', this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div align="right" class="row pagination">
  <ul class="pagination pagination">
    <li class="prev disabled"><span>Previous Label</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/some_url?page=3">3</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">Next Label</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I missed to find the <a> tag. This worked for me, Thanks

Comment: if you just want the href, then it is better to attach the handler on the anchor so you won't get undefined. If you use the first method then you would still get undefined on the `li` that does not have anchors in it

Comment: As @Huangism said if you target the anchors inside the list items, you could use the suggestion of click event..

Answer (score 1):

here is a technique very close to what you had:

```js
$("ul.pagination li a").click(function(e) {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="right" class="row pagination">
  <ul class="pagination pagination">
   <li class="prev disabled"><span>Previous Label</span></li> 
   <li class="active"><span>1</span></li> 
   <li><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="/some_url?page=3">3</a></li> 
   <li class="next"><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">Next Label</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

because elements are created dynamically,

You should provide a selector to the on function:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.pagination li', function(e) {      
  alert($(this).children('a').attr('href'));
});
```

**children() vs find()**

The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside your function call is referring to `li` element and not the `a`. You need to find `a` inside `li` and then get the attribute `href` like this

```js
$("ul.pagination li").click(function(e) {
     
     alert($(this).find('a').attr('href') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="right" class="row pagination">
  <ul class="pagination pagination">
    <li class="prev disabled"><span>Previous Label</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/some_url?page=3">3</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="/some_url?page=2" rel="next">Next Label</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```